# ASP.Net webapp JMeter login script failing

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, load-testing

It's been a while since I've used JMeter and recently started using it again to test one of our webapps here. It is a pretty standard ASP.Net 4 app, nothing crazy. I implemented a simple test script just to make sure login works as expected, but I cannot get this thing to work.

The steps are pretty simple:

```
/login.aspx
/default.aspx
/logout.aspx
/login.aspx
```

For the first login.aspx call, I'm including two parameters in the POST to pass the login name and password values that are expected. In my View Results Tree, this step does include the correct POST data and login parameters.

However, once it moves to the `/default.aspx` step, the only response I get is:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/timeout.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

It then adds a step calling the `/timeout.aspx` page, which outputs the following response:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/login.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

It then calls the `/login.aspx` page. This is the correct behavior if the user is not logged in any longer (meaning a specific session value is no longer valid or has been removed)...it redirects to `/timeout.aspx` which then forwards to `/login.aspx`. The question is why this is happening, as this is not what happens in the browser.

I have an HTTP Cookie Manager to store the session values, and the session cookie is showing up in the step request.

I figured I screwed something up so I recorded a test script with the HTTP Proxy Server and it gave me the exact same steps and results as when I manually created it, so I'm stuck at this point. I've double-checked the web site script tutorials on the JMeter site as well as around the web and it should be working.

Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am in same problem!

Answer (score 0):

...Just to ensure: do you process ViewState in your scripts?

[JMeterTesting:ASPNETViewState](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterTesting/ASPNETViewState)

[Load Testing ASP.NET Web Applications using Jmeter](http://www.qadit.com/blog/?p=1684)

Comment: Yes, I've added the VIEWSTATE processing to the couple of page calls that need it and they all still behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your cookie manager enabled if you use cookies.
http://jmeter-tips.blogspot.com/2010/02/tip-7-how-to-add-cookies-support-to.html